# Python - Creating Spotify playlist repeats the same track?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to create a Python program to create Spotify playlists according to the user's "mood"; that is, the user chooses a specific mood and the program returns a playlist where the song's (taken from the user's saved tracks) features indicate that they match said mood. However, I'm running into the issue that the playlist is made up of the same song repeated 30 times, instead of 30 different songs. I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general, so maybe this isn't a very difficult problem, but I'm trying to see the issue and I am unable to.

Here is the route in my main code that refers to this issue (my full program has more routes, which all work fine so far). All other moods will be defined by other routes, but following the same logic. Any extra code that may be necessary in order to understand the issue better, I'll provide.

```
@app.route("/playlist_mood_angry")
def mood_playlist_angry():
    # define mood and create empty track list
    selected_mood = "Angry"
    tracks_uris = [] # we need all the tracks uri to add to the future playlist
    if 'auth_header' in session:
        auth_header = session['auth_header']
        # get user profile and saved tracks
        user_profile_data = spotify.get_users_profile(auth_header)
        user_id = user_profile_data["id"]
        saved_tracks_data = spotify.get_user_saved_tracks(auth_header)
        playlist_name = 'CSMoodlet: Angry'
        playlist_description = "A playlist for when you're just pissed off and want a soundtrack to go with it. Automatically curated by CSMoodlet."

        # go through saved tracks dictionary, get the tracks and for each one check if features average matches selected mood
        for item in saved_tracks_data["items"]:
            track = item["track"]
            features = sp.audio_features(track['id'])
            acousticness = features[0]['acousticness']
            danceability = features[0]['danceability']
            energy = features[0]['energy']
            speechiness = features[0]['speechiness']
            valence = features[0]['valence']
            track_mood = spotify.define_mood(acousticness, danceability, energy, speechiness, valence)

            # if the track's mood is "angry", if the list is not 30 tracks long yet, append it to the list
            if track_mood == "Angry": #if track's mood is not Angry, it will go back to the for loop to check the next one (THIS DOESN'T WORK)
                while len(tracks_uris) < 30:
                    track_uri = "spotify:track:{}".format(track['id'])
                    tracks_uris.append(track_uri)

        # once it has gone through all saved tracks, create the playlist and add the tracks
        new_playlist = spotify.create_playlist(auth_header, user_id, playlist_name, playlist_description)
        new_playlist_id = new_playlist['id']
        added_playlist = spotify.add_tracks_to_playlist(auth_header, new_playlist_id, tracks_uris)
        playlist = spotify.get_playlist(auth_header, new_playlist_id)
        tracks_data = []
        for item in playlist["items"]:
            track_data = item["track"]
            tracks_data.append(track_data)
        return render_template("created_playlist.html", selected_mood = selected_mood, playlist_tracks=tracks_data)
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Apologies if anything is badly explained, I am new to Stackoverflow and English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error!
For anyone having issues with the same problem, I found that it was actually very simple. just substitute the while loop by an if loop, when checking the length of the playlist is less than 30.